# Firefox telnet not working

Tags: firefox, telnet

I am using Firefox to access eve-ng server.

Basically, each node is exposed as a telnet link such as the following:
`telnet://192.168.1.168:36323`
I have made sure that I have enabled the following in Firefox and restarted Firefox:
`network.protocol-handler.expose.telnet` and set the value to `false`

When clicking on the link that is a telnet link I get to select the system handler option, which when I select just launches Konsole but no telnet to the endpoint.

After searching I found the following script that I have now located in `/usr/bin` directory and from Firefox I point to this script but nothing happens:
The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh 
#address=`echo ${*##telnet://} | sed 's/:/ /g'` 

address=`echo $1 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's;/;;g'` 
port=`echo $1 | cut -d : -f 3` 
exec /usr/bin/konsole -e telnet $address $port 
#exec /usr/bin/xterm -e telnet $address $port
```

The above script works when I execute from the CLI such as following:

```
fftelnet telent://192.168.1.168:58129
```

But it does not work when I select this from Firefox.

I have attached the image of what happens in firefox:
[image: When I select fftelnet and press OK nothing happens]

Please help.

Comment: Browsers and telnet don't go very well together these days. Handshakes aren't fulfilled and a number of things have become non-compatible, from the browser's side. I am not sure why you need this, but I am certain it will never work properly. Plus, through a browser you have no keyboard to type inside a telnet session.

Comment: Hi, this is not running telnet inside the browser, this is when clicking a link which is of type telnet it will launch the system terminal and start the telnet session. Hope that explains it thanks

Comment: Insert into your script a command that echoes `$1`, `$address` and `$port` into some file in `/tmp`. You can check this way if correct parameter is passed to your script.

Comment: Hi there, I checked the output of the script and provides the correct parameters.

Comment: So maybe try replacing `telnet` with a full path to telnet binary in the command that is calling Konsole... I have no other idea... Is there maybe any error message in the Konsole window that is opened?

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Linux shell script called by Firefox in response to
# telnet:// URLs for the NNMi telnet menu.
#
address=`echo $1 | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's;/;;g'`
port=`echo $1 | cut -d : -f 3`
exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- telnet $address $port
```